# get all files within path (recursion)

Tags: c#

I wrote a method that needed to find all files within a path, and I want to get all the files using recursion. Here's my current method:

```
public void doStart(DirectoryInfo dir, string filePattern)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dir.GetFiles(filePattern))
                {
                    if (fileFound != null)
                    {
                        fileFound(fileInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    doStart(dirInfo, filePattern);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }

        public void Start(string path, string filePattern)
        {
            doStart(new DirectoryInfo(path), filePattern);
        }
```

Is there is better way to write this kind of recursion or is this good enough ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@dir, "*.filetype", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This would recursively look through the directory, finding all files with a certain filetype ('.filetype') and returns a string array containing all found files.

Also, I'd recommend not to use empty catch blocks, as your application won't let you know if something went wrong. Either show a message box (or something similar) or log it to a database or something.

Further, what would your DoStart() method do if there is a subdirectory in a subdirectory? From what I'm seeing, I'd say it only searches on 1 sublevel.

Comment: The code searches all the subdirectories in this code: `foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    doStart(dirInfo, filePattern);
                }`

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic According to MSDN, it doesn't ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx ), it only gets the subdirectories for the current directory.

Comment: This works like a charm and it's really fast.. as long as you don't set the @Dir to be "c:\\" but other than that it's nice code StefanM

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tend to use '@' when using filepaths, because I always forget to escape the '\'. I'm not sure which one of these would be faster, but I don't think there's a huge difference in speed between those options, if any.

Comment: Your answer is spot on.. I was just testing it and tried @"c:\" for example and it threw an exception there were certain folders that I didn't have access to..

Comment: @DJKRAZE And that's a perfect example which applies to this situation as to why one should handle exceptions and show and/or log them.

Comment: I agree not knocking your example it's a great example that works awesome

Comment: how can i avoid my application to crash when try to get files from location without permissions ?

Comment: I'm not sure which exception you'll get, but you can try this by creating a subdirectory in your main directory, remove access rights for yourself and run your code on the main directory. Your application should crash with an exception, and you know which exception to catch. You could catch all exceptions by using `catch (Exception ex)` and to do something with `ex` in your catch block. This way all thrown exceptions will be caught, but you'd have to manually check which exception is thrown in order to do specific actions for a specific exception.

Comment: i dont need to do it because when i am try to get all files from drive D i am get exeption: Access to the path 'D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-19' is denied.

Comment: Which exception do you get? Is it an UnauthorizedAccessException? If so, try this on your catch block:
`catch(UnauthorizedAccessException) { }` . This lets your code continue with it's job without doing anything, but doesn't do anything with the error which is thrown (which you should keep in mind).

Comment: where can i see this exception ?

Comment: Visual Studio should show the exception in a type of message box. Also, it should show up in the Output window on runtime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21347/discussion-between-stefanm-and-user1710944)

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't swallow all exceptions. If you need to ignore specific exceptions, catch those but let others bubble up
2. (style) Methods should be PascalCased (e.g. `DoStart` and `FileFound'
3. (style) Create an `OnFileFound` method instead of calling `FileFound` directly (I assume `fileFound` is an event handler?)

Other than that it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of true recursion. This will search until there are no more sub-directories to find, unlike Directory.GetFiles SearchOption.AllDirectories. You can modify this to add search filters as a parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesRecursive(string ParentDirectory)
{
    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(ParentDirectory);
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(ParentDirectory))
    {
        yield return file;
    }

    foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
    {
        foreach (string file in GetFilesRecursive(subDirectory))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}
```